# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/world

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I'm new at this area programming and I got some problems with driver, kinda:

MySql is working fine when I'm using it directly with client, problem is I can't make a connection tomcat with MySql

I put all my drivers at WEB-INF/lib

using mysql 5.7, tomcat 9.1, java 8, IntellijIdea 2016.1.1

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/world
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at Db.main(Db.java:20)

so here is my code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.sql.*;

public class Db implements Serializable{


public static void main(String args[]){
    Connection connection;
    final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/world";
    final String username = "root";
    final String pswd = "******";
    try{
        DriverManager.getDrivers();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,username,pswd);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE Name LIKE 'New%'";
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(result.next()){

            int id          = result.getInt("ID");
            String name     = result.getString("Name");
            String cCode    = result.getString("CountryCode");
            String district = result.getString("District");
            int pop         = result.getInt("Population");

            System.out.print("id = "+id+"</br>Name = "+name+
                    "</br>Code = "+cCode+"</br>District = "+district+
                    "</br>Population = "+pop+"</br>");
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: put it in tomcat/lib

Comment: Add Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); Also put mysql connector jar in lib if you haven't. I find that you have not proper url also. Correct format :  jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database_name>

Comment: @027 Your first suggestion hasn't been needed since 2007, and wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for [MySQL JDBC URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) is:

> The general format for a JDBC URL for connecting to a MySQL server is as follows, with items in square brackets ([ ]) being optional:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]][?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
> ```
>
> Here is a simple example for a connection URL:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
> ```

Your URL `jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/world` is missing a `:/` after `mysql`.

Port number defaults to `3306`, so your URL should be:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/world
```